# Is there a way to locate and print the three longest words in a string using python?

Tags: python

I need to find the three longest words in a list and index them in a text file name..

also if the list has less than three words i want it to save all three (or any number they are) of them as the text file name

any help or comments are greatly appreciated..

im sorry if i did any mistakes i am very new to coding and stack

```
print(" ")
input = input(" ")
prohibited = {'this','although','and','as','because','but','even if','he','and','however','cosmos','an','a','is','what','question :','question','[',']',',','cosmo',' ','  ','   '}
processedinput = [word for word in re.split("\W+",input) if word.lower() not in prohibited]
processedinput.sort()
processed = re.sub('[\[\]]','',repr(processedinput))



#read from database
with open(processed + '.txt',  "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write('/n'+ processed)
```

my expectations are to take any string, alphabetically `sort` it and use the 3 longest words

Comment: `sort(... ,key=len)`will use `len()` to get word's length and sort by length.

Comment: thank you! I will try it now

Comment: but how do i delete the rest after i find the 3 longest e.e its a variable so i dont know how many words will be in the user input

Comment: why to delete? Get 3 words to new variable - ie. `[:3]` or `[-3:]` - and forget rest.

Comment: Thank you :) i really need to develop a programmer mindset hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list.sort(key=len)` or `new_list = sorted(list, key=len)` to sort by word's length.

```
prohibited = {'this','although','and','as','because','but','even if','he','and','however','cosmos','an','a','is','what','question :','question','[',']',',','cosmo',' ','  ','   '}

longest = sorted(prohibited, key=len, reverse=True)[:3]

print(longest)
```

Result:

```
['question :', 'although', 'question']
```

---

But you may have many words with the same length and you may need to group them - then you can create dictinary which groups words with the same length - `{length:[word1, word2, ...]}`

```
prohibited = {'this','although','and','as','because','but','even if','he','and','however','cosmos','an','a','is','what','question :','question','[',']',',','cosmo',' ','  ','   '}

data = dict()

for item in prohibited:
    length = len(item)
    if length not in data:
        data[length] = []
    data[length].append(item)

longest_keys = sorted(data.keys(), reverse=True)[:3]
print('longest_keys:', longest_keys)

longest = [data[x] for x in longest_keys]
print('longest:', longest)
```

Result:

```
longest_keys: [10, 8, 7]
longest: [['question :'], ['although', 'question'], ['however', 'even if', 'because']]
```